# How to convert png to GeoTif

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, geotiff

I would like to convert using c# or python my png to GeoTif , what would I need? How could I implement it?
(I can use arcpy)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python and ArcPy to call the [Raster to Other Format](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-other-format.htm) tool:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "/path/to/directory"
arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion("in_images/myimage.png","out_images","TIFF")
```

This assumes of course that your PNG is already georeferenced. If not, you need to georeference it first. This is usually done with ArcMap's [Georeferencing toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm) because it requires manual intervention.